# Remove duplicates when date range changed in new vs returning customers SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

> I am checking new vs repeat customers for a period of three months. Query works perfectly when i run this for any single month but when see that for 2-3 months it shows me duplicate emailaddresses.

sample data (which shows error)

```
month emailaddress      first_order       codate       customertype
2    xyz@hotmail.com     10/27/2015       01/10/2017     Repeat
3    xyz@hotmail.com     10/27/2015       01/10/2017     Repeat
```

so basically this customer bought in jan,feb and march and his first purchase was in 2015. so that's correct he is a repeat customer but in final output i only want to see him as :
month emailaddress      first_order       codate       customertype
1    xyz@hotmail.com     10/27/2015       01/10/2017     Repeat

please keep in mind to uniquely define customers we have to use customer email,not customer id(as it was not unique)

any help would be appreciated. Here is the code which works perfect for single month but not multiple.

```
SELECT 
A.MONTH,
A.emailAddress,
A.FIRST_ORDER_EMAIL as first_order,
A.first_order as codate,
CASE WHEN CAST(A.first_order AS DATE)  =  CAST(A.FIRST_ORDER_EMAIL AS DATE) THEN 'New' ELSE 'Repeat' END customerType
FROM
(
SELECT
DATEPART(mm, s.OrderDate) AS MONTH,
c.emailAddress,
 (SELECT min(o.OrderDate)
FROM Orders o
WHERE c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID
AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN '01/01/2017 00:00' AND '03/31/2017 23:59' AND o.OrderStatus NOT IN ('cancelled','Payment Declined','Returned'))AS first_order,
 (SELECT min(o.OrderDate)
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN customers CO
ON CO.customerid = o.customerid 
WHERE c.emailAddress=CO.emailAddress
AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1/1/2010 00:00' AND '03/31/2017 23:59'
AND o.OrderStatus NOT IN ('cancelled','Payment Declined','Returned')) AS FIRST_ORDER_EMAIL
FROM orders s
JOIN orders p ON p.CustomerID = s.CustomerID
AND p.OrderID <= s.OrderID
JOIN customers c ON c.CustomerID = s.CustomerID
JOIN OrderDetails od ON od.OrderID = s.OrderID
WHERE 
 s.OrderDate BETWEEN '01/01/2017 00:00' AND '03/31/2017 23:59'
AND s.OrderStatus NOT IN ('cancelled','Payment Declined','Returned')
AND od.ProductPrice <> 0
AND od.ProductCode = 'xyz'
GROUP BY c.emailAddress,
c.CustomerID,
DATEPART(mm, s.OrderDate),
s.OrderDate
)A
GROUP BY 
A.MONTH,
A.emailAddress,
A.FIRST_ORDER_EMAIL,
A.first_order,
CASE WHEN CAST(A.first_order AS DATE)  =  CAST(A.FIRST_ORDER_EMAIL AS DATE) THEN 'New' ELSE 'Repeat' END
```

Comment: If the customer first ordered in Jan 2017 then it is New, but ordered again in Feb 2017 then it is Repeat, then ordered again in March 2017 then it is Repeat as well. You would have 3 results of 1 New and duplicate of Repeat. Your result should be just 1 New and 1 Repeat, or just 1 Repeat which is on Feb?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar result should be just one new. when he ordered in jan2017. Dont want to see duplicates in output

Comment: Which DB are you using mysql or sql server 2008?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar sql server 2008

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar It didnt returned me any records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ROW_NUMBER() to determine the first record that each emailaddress occurred

```
WITH result AS
( SELECT a.[month],
         a.emailaddress,
         a.first_order_email AS first_order,
         a.first_order AS codate,
         CASE WHEN CAST(a.first_order AS DATE)  =  CAST(a.first_order_email AS DATE)
              THEN 'New' 
              ELSE 'Repeat' 
          END customerType,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.emailaddress ORDER BY a.[month]) AS rnum
   FROM (SELECT DATEPART(mm, s.orderdate) AS [month],
                c.emailaddress,
                (SELECT min(o.orderdate)
                   FROM orders o
                  WHERE c.customerid = o.customerid
                    AND o.orderdate BETWEEN '01/01/2017 00:00' AND '03/31/2017 23:59' 
                    AND o.orderstatus NOT IN ('cancelled','Payment Declined','Returned'))AS first_order,
                (SELECT min(o.orderdate)
                   FROM orders o
                  INNER JOIN customers co
                     ON co.customerid = o.customerid 
                  WHERE c.emailaddress = co.emailaddress
                    AND o.orderdate BETWEEN '1/1/2010 00:00' AND '03/31/2017 23:59'
                    AND o.orderstatus NOT IN ('cancelled','Payment Declined','Returned')) AS first_order_email
           FROM orders s
           JOIN orders p 
             ON p.customerid = s.customerid
            AND p.orderid <= s.orderid
           JOIN customers c 
             ON c.customerid = s.customerid
           JOIN orderdetails od 
             ON od.orderid = s.orderid
          WHERE s.orderdate BETWEEN '01/01/2017 00:00' AND '03/31/2017 23:59'
            AND s.orderstatus NOT IN ('cancelled','Payment Declined','Returned')
            AND od.ProductPrice <> 0
            AND od.ProductCode = 'xyz'
          GROUP BY c.emailaddress,
                   c.customerid,
                   DATEPART(mm, s.orderdate),
                   s.orderdate
        ) a
  GROUP BY a.[month],
           a.emailaddress,
           a.first_order_email,
           a.first_order,
           CASE WHEN CAST(a.first_order AS DATE)  =  CAST(a.first_order_email AS DATE) 
                THEN 'New' 
                ELSE 'Repeat' 
            END
)

SELECT [month],
       emailaddress,
       first_order,
       codate,
       customerType
  FROM result
 WHERE rnum = 1
```

Comment: It didnt returned me any records

Comment: When you run only just the SELECT inside the WITH, are there records returned?

Comment: ..yes then records are returned..but after u added row number to query and trying it as it is no records are returned

Comment: Would you share some records returned to see the values of rnum?

Comment: ..No, I mean to say using this query as it is returned me nothing..do i have to amke some changes to this before running it?

Comment: No, just copy from "SELECT a.[month]," to ELSE 'Repeat' END" and run it. Then show some results so we can see the rnum values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152798/discussion-between-c-174-and-ferdinand-gaspar).